# What model could be the best for this problem?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, multinomial-logit

I would like to know which model could be the best for the problem i have:

I have data at baseline, at 3 months Follow-up, and data until 2 years of follow up.
I have classified individuals as if they had an event or not after 3 months and before 2 years of follow-up. (0= no event, 1= event 1, 2 = event 2)

I have some biological data (numeric) at baseline and at 3 months of follow-up.
And my goal would be to know if the biological data at baseline and 3 months could impact the occurence of event1 or event2. But not every individuals have data for the 3months follow-up.
To be precise, for the no event group i have 139 individuals at baseline, and 112 with data at M3 Follow-up; for the event 1 i have 44 and 18; for the event 2 i have 49 and 27.

And as an example i could build a dataset like this:

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),
                  time = c("M0","M3","M0","M3","M0","M0","M0","M3","M0"),
                  bio1 = c(4.2, 4.8, 4, 5, 3.8, 4.4, 5, 6, 6.1),
                  bio2 = c(12, 14, 10, 11, NA, 18, 19, 12, 15),
                  status = c(1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,1))

> data
  id time bio1 bio2 status
1  1   M0  4.2   12      1
2  1   M3  4.8   14      1
3  2   M0  4.0   10      2
4  2   M3  5.0   11      2
5  3   M0  3.8   NA      0
6  4   M0  4.4   18      0
7  5   M0  5.0   19      0
8  5   M3  6.0   12      0
9  6   M0  6.1   15      1
```

Status variable refers to the event occurence. M0 is baseline, and M3 the 3months follow-up.

Thank you in advance for your comments!

Comment: You have censored data, so this will probably require survival analysis.

Comment: Why is it that not all individuals have data at 3 months follow-up ? Is there a biological reason or is it simply drop-out ?

Comment: @user2974951 No event-times and he always knows the status after 2 years. I think this is more of a missing values situation rather than censorship in a survival setting.

Comment: @CaroZ i decided to not look at biological data for those who had event1 or event2 before the 3 months Follow-up. So for example, 44 had the event1, but 21 had it after 3months(and there 3 had missing datas so we go down to 18 available data at M3)